# Flash the local drives, scan and retrieve deleted files with vsc++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, data-recovery

Does anyone know how to be able to list down all the working local drives ( like drive C, D, removable disks and so on..) through combo box? And with that, I could be able to scan that specific drive and retrieve all the deleted files in it. I mean, to recover those files that have been deleted through formatting or by pressing shift+delete.

Just the functions that would be needed to do all of these stuffs would be enough though. By the way,

I know it would be hard if I would be using high-level language like Java and C# to do that, so visual c++ is the one I've been working on.

That's it! I hope to get positive response from you guys. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You want us to write the code for a file recovery utility for you? I don't think that's going to happen, no matter how nicely you ask. This is a lot more complicated and difficult than you seem to understand, considering your question ends with "That's it!" There are entire companies with products like this as their flagship applications. If it were completely trivial, these companies wouldn't exist. A search will reveal plenty of questions covering similar topics that will help get you started.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recovering deleted file on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837307/recovering-deleted-file-on-windows), [C# classes to undelete files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819188/c-sharp-classes-to-undelete-files) (yes, it says C#, but the code is all P/Invoked, so it's trivial to translate to C++)

Comment: I suggest you learn the internals and implementation details of NTFS. It's not a simple task and has every chance of compleely screwing up a drive.

Answer (score 0):

Use TestDrive
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download
Its open source and works great

Answer (score -1):

pull the drive out of the unit, if it's NTFS, go get getdataback for NTFS.
Install it on a windows computer, slave this drive to the system and scan it for deleted files.

It will show all the ntfs structures, even deleted or destroyed ones.

It's not free but will be the best $100 you ever spent if it saves your files.