# Access file before it's deleted

Tags: c#, windows, .net-4.0, filesystemwatcher

Is it possible to access a file before it's deleted when using `FileSystemWatcher.OnDeleted` event?

I'm storing some data about the document itself in its metadata and i need that info before it's deleted.

Any Ideas how to accomplish this with or without `FileSystemWatcher` if it's even possible ?

**Update ://**

I realized that storing the data in the file is bad as i cannot access it when file is deleted.

**Solution** : rewrite my app to store the data in a local database(sqlite/xml or something like that) as i get the full path and name when the file is being created/renamed/updated/deleted it would be easier to update the database record for the file.

Thanks to all for the ideas and suggestions!

Comment: I almost want to say no you cannot because the event fires once the file has been deleted.  I do not believe the FSW can know of the event until after it has completed, since that would mean a pre-delete even would need to be fired and captured, and then allow for you to create a lock on the file.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with just `FileSystemWatcher`. I'm not sure if Windows allows a lower-level hook (though I doubt it.)

Comment: You would get the fullname from the eventhandler. Use it to restore the file, make it invisible, read it, and delete it. hackish and not foolproof, but still something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837307/recovering-deleted-file-on-windows

Comment: @nawfal that won't work. You will get a `FileNotFoundException` if you try to access the file in the event handler.

Comment: @GETah yes, that is why I was asking him to restore the file from recyclebin, read it and then delete again. From the eventhandler he would get the name and associated properties of the file for sure! just that he cant access the file itself

Comment: Is it possible in Win32 to create a hard link to a file? If so, you could hardlink the file to another (temp) file, read the temp file, then delete it; both files should then have been deleted by the OS by then.

Comment: @Loadmaster but he doesnt know before being deleted, that's the issue here. So which file to hardlink here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to access a file before it's deleted when using
>   FileSystemWatcher.OnDeleted event?

The event is triggered after the file deletion not before, so you won't be able to access the file when this event is raised.

> Any Ideas how to accomplish this if it's even possible ?

I would use the `OnChanged` event instead, which is fired every time the file changes. Basically, you read the file metadata every time the file changes. This can be a bit cumbersome if the file gets updated very often but should allow you to have the latest metadata before the file is removed.

Comment: OnChanged need not necessarily fire before OnDelete!

Comment: also there is no guarantee the file will be changed before it's deleted.

Comment: @Aviatrix If the file is not changed before its deleted than there is nothing to read from it.

Comment: if the file is not changed and deleted, still there are stuffs to read from it. This solution wont work actually

Comment: @nawfal Except the file descriptor data that can be retrieved on `OnCreate` event, I do not see what the OP can read from an empty file :)

Comment: @GETah file isn't empty , it's downloaded , but i see your point , i could store the data in a list in the app and then access the info about the file from that info

Comment: He can still read if you do not assume the file is fresh and empty. What about the case of existing files?

Comment: @nawfal They could always do an initial scan on startup to capture files that are already there.

Comment: @PaulPhillips all those are possible, but how do we dare to assume the initial scanning etc etc are all just a breeze? You know never know the number of files or if the files are already existing ones or not or anything abt OP's files. The safest way here is to give one general approach which is what this answer fails to give.

Comment: @nawfal We're answering other people's technical problems over the internet.  If you don't make any assumptions, you'll never be able to answer anything.

Comment: @PaulPhillips that's not entirely right for programmers. But yeah seldom we need to, but with an element of enquiring, not with a stamp of authority. Anyhow the disucssion I was having here was nothing related to the work around you suggested here which is welcome btw :)

Comment: @nawfal PaulPhillips is right. If you are a programmer then you should not look for a fully cooked backed solution. You should be looking for elements that will help you out build a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
FileSystemWatcher1 = Your Main Watcher.
FileSystemWatcher2 = RecycleBin Watcher

If the FileSystemWatcher1 Deleted file == the FileSystemWatcher2 Created File
{
    //Do what you want with the FileSystemWatcher2.FullPath
}
```